# Visual Studio replaces curly quotes by straight ones in XAML attributes

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

If there is some way to prevent it? Even if managed to input something, it's getting replaced while Auto-Formatting.

I could use things like “&#8220;”, but it's not very comfortable (I use an app which allows to input those symbols using simple keyboard shortcuts; also, of course, readability of source code would be decreased).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid the ““” notation, you can avoid the auto-formatting either by using a Resx or by avoid using the inline property.

Resx:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static resx:Resources.MyQuotedText}" />
```

Full property:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>“Something“</TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already knew about this way, but forgot to mention. I doubt it'll work everywhere though (what about, let's say, StringFormat?), so maybe it's time to me to learn how to use resx instead.

Comment: I have to admit that I have never tried this syntax with StringFormat nor had any StringFormat with the curly quotes. The resx is quite useful if you plan to translate the app but the downside is to have something more complex if you want only one language.